# jQuery slideToggle and change text

Tags: jquery

I have a simple faq section that needs to expand to show the answers on click of the question, easy enough. I can't seem to get the span (-/+) to change correctly. It either doesn't work at all or changes all of them at once, not just the one contained inside the question.

```
dd{display:none;}

$('.faq dt').on('click', function(){
    var span = $('.faq dt span');
    $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('fast');
    $(span).text( $(span).text() == '[ + ]' ? '[ - ]' : "[ + ]");
});

<dl class="faq">
    <dt>this is question 1<span>[ + ]</span></dt>
    <dd>this is answer 1</dd>
    <dt>this is question 2<span>[ + ]</span></dt>
    <dd>this is answer 2</dd>
    <dt>this is question 3<span>[ + ]</span></dt>
    <dd>this is answer 3</dd>
</dl>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8mAC/)

how do I target only the span inside the clicked element?

Comment: nope my bad it doesnt xD, adeneo posted a good answer though have a look

Comment: yup, thank you for looking though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find()` finds the span inside the `dd`

```
$(function(){
    $('.faq dt').click(function(){
        $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('fast').end()
               .find('span').text(function(_,t) {
            return t == '[ + ]' ? '[ - ]' : "[ + ]";
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8mAC/1/)

Comment: .find()! thank you, was not remembering that - what does the (function(_,t) mean?

Comment: it's just text() with a callback function

Comment: Is that what that is for? No idea. Unfortunately I still have to wait 2 minutes to accept your answer - oh wait its not even your answer